# Type 'Canvas' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Canvas>'

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm doing some FE development for the first time in quite some time, and I'm puzzled by a TypeScript issue I'm getting when trying to use Redux in Typescript.

I'm following the instructions on the Redux Toolkit site (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript) to setup redux with Typescript.

With this simple code (almost identical to the example code in the docs):

```js
import { PayloadAction, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { fabric } from "fabric";
import { RootState } from "./store";

// Define a type for the slice state
type EditorState = {
    canvas: fabric.Canvas | undefined;
};

// Define the initial state using that type
const initialState: EditorState = {
    canvas: undefined,
};

export const editorSlice = createSlice({
    name: "editor",
    // `createSlice` will infer the state type from the `initialState` argument
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        // Use the PayloadAction type to declare the contents of `action.payload`
        setCanvas: (state, action: PayloadAction<fabric.Canvas>) => {
            state.canvas = action.payload; // <--- state.canvas is where the error is
        },
    },
});

export const { setCanvas } = editorSlice.actions;

// Other code such as selectors can use the imported `RootState` type
export const getCanvas = (state: RootState) => state.editor.canvas;

export default editorSlice.reducer;
```

I get the following error under `state.canvas` in the line `state.canvas = action.payload;`:

```
Type 'Canvas' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Canvas>'.
  The types of '_activeObject.fill' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'string | Pattern | Gradient | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | WritableDraft<Pattern> | WritableDraft<Gradient> | undefined'.
      Type 'Pattern' is not assignable to type 'string | WritableDraft<Pattern> | WritableDraft<Gradient> | undefined'.
        Type 'Pattern' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Pattern>'.
          Types of property 'source' are incompatible.
            Type 'string | HTMLImageElement' is not assignable to type 'string | WritableDraft<HTMLImageElement>'.
              Type 'HTMLImageElement' is not assignable to type 'string | WritableDraft<HTMLImageElement>'.
                Type 'HTMLImageElement' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<HTMLImageElement>'.
                  Types of property 'offsetParent' are incompatible.
                    Type 'Element | null' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Element> | null'.
                      Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Element>'.
                        The types of 'ownerDocument.body.shadowRoot' are incompatible between these types.
                          Type 'ShadowRoot | null' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<ShadowRoot> | null'.
                            Type 'ShadowRoot' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<ShadowRoot>'.
                              Types of property 'adoptedStyleSheets' are incompatible.
                                Type 'CSSStyleSheet[]' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<CSSStyleSheet>[]'.
                                  Type 'CSSStyleSheet' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<CSSStyleSheet>'.
                                    Types of property 'ownerNode' are incompatible.
                                      Type 'Element | ProcessingInstruction | null' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Element> | WritableDraft<ProcessingInstruction> | null'.
                                        Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Element> | WritableDraft<ProcessingInstruction> | null'.
```

I can't work out what the problem is. If I change the `canvas` key to be a string, everything works as expected.

Any help much appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two problems here, one conceptual and one technical.

The conceptual problem is that a `fabric.Canvas` is not "data", and thus doesn't belong in the Redux state.  [You should *only* put plain JS objects and arrays into Redux](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions).  That `fabric.Canvas` is neither, and should be held in the UI layer.

The specific error is that something about Immer's TS typing explodes when you put a deeply nested / recursive object like a DOM node or similar into the Redux state.  (But that's sort of a *good* thing in this case, because it's exploding when you're trying to do something you shouldn't do anyway :)  )

Comment: You're right - I overlooked the fact that the underlying Canvas is a class, not an object. Thanks for the reply!